# Why is my function not outputting what I am returning?

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to write a piece of code that justifies an input by inserting extra spaces between words, so that its length is exactly 40 characters.

I have written a function that I think should do this;

```
string justify(int size, string s) {
    while (size < 40) {
        for (int p = 0; p < size; p++) {
            if (s[p] == ' ') {
                s.insert(p, " ");
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

However, when I call the function later;

```
justify(words.size(), words);
```

Nothing happens. I am defining the string in `int main()` and am then calling the function. Why is it not working?

Comment: Why `while (size < 40) {`, given that `size` doesn't change?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're printing what the function returns. If you don't print or store its result, it is just discarded.

Comment: You don't need to pass the size of the string to the function; it is `s.size()` (and `s` is unaffected by modifications to the string). Are you sure that this function isn't supposed to take the justification width as an argument instead?

Comment: Reading out loud: If the string is shorter than 40 characters, double all spaces at positions between 0 and the string's original size; if the string is still shorter than 40 characters, double all spaces at positions between 0 and the string's original size; if the string is still shorter than 40 characters, double all spaces at positions between 0 and the string's original size... Can you spot a problem with this algorithm?

Comment: Can you point to the line of code that you think outputs something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a huge amount of bugs in your code: `size` is not bound to `s.size()` (and you actually need `s.size()`). The inner loop will be infinite too, because *p* was growing with the same speed as `s.size()`. This is the fixed algorithm - I marked three main changes with inline comments.

But it is not correct for strings without any spaces at all.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string justify (string s)
{
  int l = s.size();
  while (s.size () < 40)
  {
    for (int p = 0; p < s.size() && s.size () < 40; p++) {
      // s.size () < 40 - not to add odd spaces

      if (s[p] == ' ')
      {
        s = s.insert(p, " ");

        while(p < s.size() && s[p] == ' ')
          p++; // Now p grows faster than s.size()

      }
    }
    if (l == s.size()) { // If no spaces in s!
        break;
    }
    l = s.size();
  }
  return s;
}

int main ()
{
  cout << justify("HelloWorld");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The subject, as far as the code you wrote, I really don't understand it. Are you sure that when the size is greater than 40, your program will not fall into an infinite loop?

Another point: I hope you notice that what you pass to the function is a copy of the string. If you want to modify your string in *justify*, then you need to pass a reference (`&`), or, after *justify* returns, follow assign values in main, such as "str = justify(...);"

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: What do you mean by *"follow assign values in main"* (seems incomprehensible)? Can you elaborate?